# Nothing is changing when I edit the code in Vue

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

I just started to use Vue.js and for backend I have Laravel 5.

The problem is the following: I try to edit any data, or component or even the HTML in a view page, but nothing is changing and I have no idea why.

The existing website has a working page, done with Vue. But when I try to modify something from the source `.vue` file, nothing changes.

Maybe it has something to do with cache, have no idea...

I am not using npm, I just got the code, running in a Linux VM, under apache.

--

My package.json starts like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
```

But on the machine I can't find npm installed. Is this possible? What's going on in here?

**update**

I fixed installation of npm and node, but when running `npm run dev` I get errors. Check the error log [here](https://pastebin.com/E49D5e5Q)

Comment: Try `npm run watch` and see!

Comment: I am not using npm, I just got the code, running in a Linux VM, under apache.

Comment: @HirenGohel Is one supposed to `run watch` every time the code is modified??

Comment: @Ben I require more information. If you are not using node then what are you using? xampp, mamp? The website needs to be on a server of some kind. You cannot just change the files.

Comment: @ShaneG I think I'm using wamp. I am able to modify other files, from simple php or laravel code, but not Vue.

Comment: I added info from `package.json`

Comment: Yes, if you are using node, then every time you need to rune that command!

Comment: @Ben Ok yeah you are using wamp. And you are also using npm! lol On a command line type "npm -v" and see what that comes up with. That will check if npm is installed and its version. If thats not installed and the code requires it, then that your problem.

Comment: @ShaneG nmp was not installed, I installed it, run the watch command, gives not found errors on the scripts defined in config.json....

Comment: @Ben From looking at the package.json it looks like you will have to install the packages it requires. Google "npm webpack" or whatever your package is and you will find an npm page for it. This link will come in handy: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using Laravel you have to install all dependencies with NPM [(node)](https://nodejs.org/en/). You do that by running `npm install` in your command line in the directory of the Laravel project.

After that, all pre defined dependencies by Laravel (Such as Vue but also Axios and jQuery, see the Package.json file) are installed.

To use the Vue components (And other assets  like JS code and scss) you have to compile them. With a fresh Laravel project you do that by `npm run dev` that will compile all your js/scss's in the resources/assets folder. So if you make a change to the Example.vue file (That is always installed with a fresh project) you run `npm run dev` and if everything was ok you are able to see the new changes.

To make things easier you can run `npm run watch`. This command will constantly check if you make changes to the assets. So if that command is active, and you make a change to a Vue component, it will automatically compile for you.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks, it's now more clear to me. However, I still can't reach a successful run due to a script. `"development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",` Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: Try to update your `npm`, otherwise I don't exactly know.